# What does $\dim \operatorname{Im}(3I − T) = 1$ can tell me about $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation. Suppose it is known that $T(1, 1, 1) = (2, 2, 2)$ and that $\dim \operatorname{Im}(3I − T) = 1$ (where I is the identity transformation on $\mathbb{R}^3$). Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable.

---

First, we have that $T(1, 1, 1) = 2(1, 1, 1)$ which means that $\lambda=2$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

But what does $\dim \operatorname{Im}(3I − T) = 1$ can tell me about $T$?

If, for example, we had that $\dim \ker(T-3I) = 1$, we would know that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with algebraic multiplicity of $1$, but I do not understand what the Image dimension of $(3I-T)$ can tell me.

Comment: It’s algebraic multiplicity, not multiplication

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rank-Nullity Theorem tells you that

$$ \dim \ker (3I-T) + \dim \operatorname{Im}(3I − T) = 3,$$

so $\dim \ker (3I-T)=2$ and thus $3$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I always thought that $\dim\ker$ gives the geometric multiplicity, not the algebraic. How does this automatically imply $T$ is diagonalisable?

Comment: @FShrike since algebraic multiplicity $\geq$ geometric multiplicity, the sum of the algebraic multiplicities equals $3$, and $\lambda=2$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$, we know the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=2$ has to be $1$ and $T$ is diagonalizable

Comment: @MatthewPilling A matrix is diagonalisable if, for every eigenvalue, its geometric multiplicity equals its algebraic multiplicity? I deduce this from the Jordan form

Comment: @FShrike Yes. Geometric multiplicity$=$algebraic multiplicity for each eigenvalue implies diagonalizable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my only concern here is that you calculated $\dim ker(3I-T)$ to be $2$, but why does it guarantee that $\dim Ker(T-3I)$ is also $2$?

Comment: They're the same thing. If $(3I-T)v=0$, then $(T-3I)v=-0=0$. The two kernels are the same. This is why it is a matter of convention whether or not you define the characteristic polynomial by $\det(A-\lambda I)$ or $\det(\lambda I-A)$! @CalculusLover

Comment: @FShrike Great, thank you!! :)